# Combine Results of Observables into one final array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an Observable of which I want to `map` each item in and use to call another Observable with said item. During this process, the second Observable should be subscribed to and its results appended to an array. At the end of all of this, I want to set this array to some public property in my component.

- Retrieve list of items from service method
- For each item in the list, call another service method with said item
- Append results to array
- Set array to public property on component

I'm thinking that I may have to `combineLatest` or `forkJoin`. Any ideas?

---

Previous, working as expected code:

```
this.myService.getForests().subscribe(forests => {
    forests.forEach(forest => {
        const name: string = forest.forestName;
        const provider: string = forest.provider;
        this.myService.getDomains(provider, forestName).subscribe(domains => {
            this._domains.push.apply(this._domains, domains);
        });
    });
});
```

---

Code that I've been trying to refactor and not yielding expected results:

```
this.myService.getForests()
   .combineLatest(forests => forests.map(forest => this.myService.getDomains(forest.provider, forest.forestName)))
   .subscribe(domains => this._domains.push.apply(this._domains, domains));
```

Comment: For each item in list you may call .map() method. Bet best what what you can do - show your code and data model.

Comment: @andrey.shedko I added more code for clarity

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions here is to map your forests into observables and flatMap `getForests()` into a `forkJoin` observable from your mapped observables:

```
this.myService.getForests().flatMap(forests => 
    Observable.forkJoin(forests.map(forest =>
        this.myService.getDomains(forest.provider, forest.forestName)))
.subscribe(domains => this._domains.push.apply(this._domains, domains));
```

Comment: Funny that you mention this because I had to something similar elsewhere in my code and this solution worked. Would you be able to explain a bit as to why it does?